# Get query strings and append to link

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript novice, thanks in advance.

I'd like to get the the full string of query parameters and append them all to a link in the body. The link in the body will send the user to a registration website so I'd need those query strings to carry over to the next site. I'm thinking this would be the best way to do it, if not, please advise.

Example: `http://example.com?utm_source=Twitter&utm_medium=HostedEvent&utm_campaign=Event2015`

I'd like go grab `?utm_source=Twitter&utm_medium=HostedEvent&utm_campaign=Event2015` and add it to a link in the body

Link: `<a href="http://otherdomain.com-add query strings here dynamically">Register</a>`

Comment: is the first string in the url? or just treated as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the link in the html link does not have other parameters and that you add a class to it so we can target it

```
<a href="http://otherdomain.com" class="copy-url-params">Register</a>
```

Then you need the following script

```
$(function(){
   var urlparams = window.location.search;
   $('.copy-url-params').prop('href', function(idx, current){
      return current + urlparams;
   });
});
```

Comment: I figured it was less complex than I was making it in my head. I'll give this a try, thank you.